# Licenses for SQL Server Mirroring with Witness

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing, mirroring

I'm developing an application for a client and I need to use SQL Server and he needs High Availability.

I have a question about licenses I can use to have a mirroring configuration and a witness database.

In this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx), in the "High Availability (AlwaysOn)" section, row "Database mirroring", It says that Standard edition supports it, but Web and Express are witness only.

Does it mean that I need 2 instances with Standard edition and one may be either Express either Web?

It it possible to achieve the mirroring with the web Edition?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.  You need two instances of at least Standard edition to support the mirror; the witness server simply "witnesses" the need to automatically fail over between the Principal and the Mirror.  This witness can be either Web Edition or Express.

You can have a mirror without the witness, but there will be no automatic failover.

Comment: A passive license is included with an active license, so you don't need two licenses.  See "fail-over" licensing in the SQL licensing guides.  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql+licensing+guide&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F6%2F4%2FA%2F64A1EC8F-F575-41E1-9D34-821FA9F98F8E%2FSQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf&ei=r8sKUefqMcqp0AHo84CgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFSXG4gy3jubnnd6Co46zDLxdyBRA

Comment: You are correct; I should have used the word instance instead of license.  Corrected.